# is there a short way to load generics in listmodel?

Tags: java, swing

my JList is holding a model that represents a

```
ArrayList<? extends MyObject> myModel;
```

in order to fill or get data I iterate it.
Is there a nicer way to get that desired list?

I tried

```
list = new ArrayList<myObj>();
Collections.addAll(list, myModel.toArray())
```

but cause the array is object then it doesnt work.

is there a shorter way to load generics in listmodel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
List<MyObject> list = java.util.Arrays.asList((MyObject[]) mymodel.toArray());
```

Comment: almost. my model is probably defined as an Object type. it gives a compile error that I should change my list to list<object>. is there a way to define my object model as specific object type?

Comment: If mymodel.toArray() returns an Array only with MyObjects, then you could try to cast: (MyObject[]) mymodel.toArray().

Comment: I added the mentioned cast to my answer.

Comment: because my list is <? extends IDisplayable> it throws ClassCastException

Answer (score -1):

generics in a ListModel will be supported in jdk7. If you dont want to wait, you might consider to grab its sources from openJDK

Comment: curious ... who considers this answer as incorrect/inappropriate and why?

Comment: Not me, but this answer looks more like a (knowledgeable) comment. As an aside, I generally reserve down-votes for misleading answers that go uncorrected despite a clarifying comment. On the other hand, one can hold out for the relevant [badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/38/peer-pressure). :-)

Comment: @trashgod hmm .. then the borderline between answer and comment seems a bit ... wobbly. Thanks. And LOL - there's quite a bunch of cool badges available :-)